# Messed up a merge when trying to upgrade my Laravel application

Tags: git, laravel, github, merge

I have an existing laravel project which used an older version of Laravel 5.1. I wanted to upgrade my project to use Laravel 5.1.2.

I followed [this](http://viget.com/extend/keeping-the-framework-for-your-application-up-to-date-with-git) tutorial. So I added the `laravel/laravel` github repository into my git project as a remote called `laravel`, fetched it, then I created a new local branch named `framework` using `laravel/master` as the remote.

Then I switched back to my `develop` branch, ran `git merge framework` and fixed all the conflicts, then I ran `git commit -m "Upgrade to Laravel 5.1.2" && git push`

Now here comes the problem, after I pushed I noticed my `develop` branch got **all** the commits (over 4000) from the laravel/laravel project, which I really do not want littering my git log. Is there any way to not have to add all the commits from the framework, but only the "Upgrade to Laravel 5.1.2" message? Is it possible to fix this afterwards anymore?

EDIT:
Okay, I managed to fix my current commit history like this:

`git reset --soft HEAD~1
git commit -am "...."
git push --force`

**but** I have no idea how it magically got fixed with that, and how can I in the future avoid littering my commit history when merging a big remote repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you did the `git reset --soft HEAD~1`, you "moved backwards" a commit, while keeping your working directory and index the same. So when you committed, the files were changed as if you had done the merge, without doing an actual merge; i.e., your commit had only one parent. I'm not sure if that is something I would recommend, as when you merge again git will not know when you last merged, which may cause issues. However, if you wish to "merge" again in the future without actually merging (i.e. you don't want the history of the branch you are "merging" in), pass the `--squash` option to `git merge`. This will bring in the changes, but not the history.